Fiance visa, didn’t mention girlfriend on previous visit applications
My friend and his girlfriend (a British citizen) are in a long term relationship, almost 8 years now. They're in the process of applying for a fiance visa.
They meet every requirement: finances, relationship proof including calls, texts, plane tickets, pictures of them together etc.. The problem is that he visited her a lot on 6 month visit visas overtime, but have never mentioned that he's visiting her. He just mentioned it was for tourism.
Will this prevent him from being able to get a fiance visa? Is he basically screwed or the home office won’t look at it too deeply?

Not sure I understand the concern... Was there any question about girlfriends in the visa applications?

on a visit visa for the UK, it does not ask you if you have a girlfriend or not. it does ask you if you have family members, but a girlfriend isn't legally your family member and therefore you're legally single. what he's worried about is that he never mentioned he's visiting his girlfriend (to avoid high risk of refusal) he never broke any visa rule though. he's asked a lot of people and a lot are telling him they doubt the home office would look deeply into it.

So.... you want another bunch of people to tell you that here?

no he just wants to make sure 100% that there's no problem with that as in hearing from similar experiences from other people. the application is like 2000 pounds so he doesn't want to take the risk of losing all of that for nothing.

So if some anonymous rando on the Internet tells him "it's a problem" he'll cancel the wedding? If so, that is a problem.

It is also a problem if he ever reaches 100% certainty based on what he hears from strangers on the internet. We might all be wrong.

I mean.. it's probably for comfort I guess

So he was economical with the truth about the (main?) purpose of his visits to the UK for 8 years?  And now he’s in the awkward position of wanting UKVI to accept there is actually a long-standing relationship? I’d have a few sleepless nights over the possible repercussions of the inconsistency too. But the only way to find our is to apply.

he talked with a lawyer and they've told him it's fine and a lot of people were in the same position and got approved.
